# SOAP WSDL Error: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'soapenc:Array.'

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Below is a snippet of my wsdl that I'm having an issue with.

This is working, but I'm getting a validation error.

*src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'soapenc:Array.' It was detected that 'soapenc:Array' is in namespace 'schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/';, but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document.*

I added this to definitions in my wsdl: xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"

```
<xsd:complexType name="getSalesTaxInformation_Array">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="productTax" type="tns:getSalesTaxInformation"
                                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**What does this error mean and how do I get rid of it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I figured it out. The error went away after I added these inside my schema element.

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
```

I don't know where I found the solution, but here's some information about using the Array thing in the wsdl.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Writing_WSDL_Contracts/files/WSDLDefiningArrays.html